# Wysiwyg component to use inside my Android app?

Tags: android, wysiwyg

My Android app lets users write `HTML` fragments.

WYSIWYG would be nice, but is there a [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) widget available for the Android UI?
Or do you know a JavaScript-based WYSIWYG component that works in an Android `WebView`?

Preferably usable in an Open Source app. Ideally Open Source itself.

Answer (score 2):

There's a very simple and native Wysiwyg editor in android.

You can find the source code in the Wordpress app for Android:
https://android.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/org/wordpress/android/editPost.java#L634

Download their free app to try it out:
https://market.android.com/details?id=org.wordpress.android

The license is GPL.

Comment: +1 thanks! I will try. It looks very basic but definitely better than nothing, and adding images/fonts support is probably doable.

Comment: Looks like editing a pre-existing HTML string is not supported though: http://android.forums.wordpress.org/topic/can-i-edit-in-wysiwyg